# Getting Noclassdeffounderror on working with Google places API android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-places-api

I am working on a tutorial found on this link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

I am getting the following error on clicking the button:

```
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.PlacesMapActivity
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:110)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:200)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-13 12:28:03.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9180):     ... 12 more
```

The placesmapactivity.java class is shown below:

```
package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class PlacesMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    // Nearest places
    PlacesList nearPlaces;

    // Map view
    MapView mapView;

    // Map overlay items
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    // Map controllers
    MapController mc;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    OverlayItem overlayitem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_places);

        // Getting intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Users current geo location
        String user_latitude = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
        String user_longitude = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");

        // Nearplaces list
        nearPlaces = (PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("near_places");

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // Geopoint to place on map
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude) * 1E6),
                (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude) * 1E6));

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable_user = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user, this);

        // Map overlay item
        overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
                "That is you!");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        mc = mapView.getController();

        // These values are used to get map boundary area
        // The area where you can see all the markers on screen
        int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // check for null in case it is null
        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
            // loop through all the places
            for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {
                latitude = place.geometry.location.lat; // latitude
                longitude = place.geometry.location.lng; // longitude

                // Geopoint to place on map
                geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                        (int) (longitude * 1E6));

                // Map overlay item
                overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, place.name,
                        place.vicinity);

                itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);


                // calculating map boundary area
                minLat  = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
                minLong = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
                maxLat  = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
                maxLong = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
            }
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            // showing all overlay items
            itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
        }

        // Adjusting the zoom level so that you can see all the markers on map
        mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));

        // Showing the center of the map
        mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
        mapView.postInvalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


The button click code is shown below:

btnShowOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    PlacesMapActivity.class);
            // Sending user current geo location
            i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
            i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));

            // passing near places to map activity
            i.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
            // staring activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Check line number `207`.

Comment: Do you build your project with maven?

Comment: No i am not building with maven.

Comment: @Aniruddha,What do u mean?.I saw the line no 207."Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW" comment placed there.